# Terraform External Provider resource does not have attribute for variable during plan phase

Tags: terraform

When running terraform plan with the below scripts I Gert the following error message:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:

* output.foobaz: Resource 'data.external.example' does not have attribute 'result.foobaz' for variable 'data.external.example.result.foobaz'
```

It doesn't appear from testing that the external script is actually executed during the plan phase, however, it does appear that the plan phase is trying to interpolate the expected response, which seem s incorrect to me. Is there something I'm missing?

```
provider "scaleway" {
  region = "ams1"
}

resource "scaleway_ip" "swarm_manager_ip" {
  count = 1
}

data "external" "example" {
  program = ["./scripts/test.sh"]

  query = {
    # arbitrary map from strings to strings, passed
    # to the external program as the data query.
    foo = "${scaleway_ip.swarm_manager_ip.0.ip}"
    baz = "i-am-baz"
  }
}

output "foobaz" {
  value = "${data.external.example.result.foobaz}"
}

output "scaleway_ip_address" {
  value = "${scaleway_ip.swarm_manager_ip.0.ip}"
}
```

Here is the external script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit if any of the intermediate steps fail
set -e

# Extract "foo" and "baz" arguments from the input into
# FOO and BAZ shell variables.
# jq will ensure that the values are properly quoted
# and escaped for consumption by the shell.
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "FOO=\(.foo) BAZ=\(.baz)"')"

# Placeholder for whatever data-fetching logic your script implements
FOOBAZ="$FOO BAZ"

# Safely produce a JSON object containing the result value.
# jq will ensure that the value is properly quoted
# and escaped to produce a valid JSON string.
jq -n --arg foobaz "$FOOBAZ" '{"foobaz":$foobaz}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Terraform syntax is incorrect. `data.external.example.result` is a map. To access its entry `foobaz` you need to code

```
"${data.external.example.result["foobaz"]}"
```

See https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html